# Abrir pagina html no modal

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, modal

Tenho as seguintes páginas html: **cadastrocliente**, **cadastroendereço** e **cadastrocontato**.

No meu **cadastrocliente** eu tenho dois buttons: `id="btnCadastroEndereco"` e `id="btnCadastroContato"`.

Quando eu clico nesses buttons gostaria de abrir seu respectivo html em um modal `id="myModal"` (Por exemplo quando eu clico no button `btnCadastroContato` gostaria de abrir o **cadastrocontato**.html no modal ou seja como mudaria o conteúdo usaria apenas um modal para resolver esse problema)

```
 $('#btnCadastroContato').click(function(){
           ('#myModal').modal('show'); 
           // Isso abre o modal, mas como eu faço 
para o modal abrir com o conteudo html da minha pagina cadastrocontato?
    });
```

estou utilizando o jquery.js, bootstrap.js e php.

Comment: você está usando qual tecnologia no servidor? asp net? php? node?

Comment: estou utilizando php

Answer (score 2):

Tenho uma solução que vc pode usar, mas a página onde o modal vai estar precisa estar em .php. Não precisa de script nem nada. É bem simples na verdade só precisa inclur `<?php include 'cadastrocontato.html';?>` no modal.

**Obs1:** não funciona para chamar páginas de "terceiros" tipo (http://www.globo.com/), ela só vai chamar o arquivo .html do seu diretório.

**Obs2:** vc tem que formatar o `html` para encaixar dentro do Modal!

```
<!-- Trigger button do modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <?php include 'cadastrocontato.html';?> <!-- Aqui vc chama a sua página -->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **Abrindo Dois modais um em cada BTN**

Onde está `<!-- Aqui vc chama a sua página -->` vc coloca o seu .html que está no diretório.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
    
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal1">
        Modal 1
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">CONTATO</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            Condeudo do mudal 1 : <pre>&lt;?php include 'contato1.html'; ?&gt;</pre> <!-- Aqui vc chama a sua página -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2">
        Modal 2
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">ENDEREÇO</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            Condeudo do mudal 2 : <pre>&lt;?php include 'contato2.html'; ?&gt;</pre> <!-- Aqui vc chama a sua página -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Certo, mas eu tenho duas paginas para chamar. em um momento a pagina de contato e em outro a pagina de endereço. como vou conseguir fazer para saber qual include devo chamar?

Comment: Bruno pelo que li na sua pergunta eu entendi que vc vai ter 2 botões correto? Então basta fazer dois Modais com IDs diferentes. Faz Dois Buttons e em cada um coloca o id do Modal data-target="#exampleModal1" e data-target="#exampleModal2" e no Modal div id="exampleModal1"  e div id="exampleModal2"  e dentro de cada Modal <?php include 'cadastrocontato.html';?> e <?php include 'cadastroendereco.html';?>

Comment: @BrunoAparecidodaSilva inclui na resposta o código de como chamar os **Dois Modais**.

Comment: Entendi, do jeito que você falou funciona, porém eu tenho um modal só e eu posso usar ele para abrir as duas páginas ... essa é lógica

Comment: eu tenho <div class="modal-body">... será que não tem como eu pegar o .html dessa div e coloca a minha pagina dentro? algo do tipo $('#div').html(cadastrocontato.php ou .html) e o mesmo p/ o endereço $('#div').html(cadastroendereco.php ou .html)

Comment: @BrunoAparecidodaSilva eu não tenho conhecimento de JS para te ajudar nessa rss. Mas vc pode pensar em uma lógica que dependendo do Btn que ele clicar (1 ou 2) ele chama o `include` 1 ou 2 dentro da `<div class="modal-body">`

Comment: Obrigado, vou tentar dar uma pesquisada ou ver se alguem consegue me ajudar kkkkk