# É possível abrir página php dentro de modal?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, modal, gráfico

Em todos os sistemas com gráficos que eu fiz, existia uma página que pegava os registros do banco de dados e exibia cada registro com um botão que redirecionava para sua determinada página de gráfico.

Dessa vez eu queria que esse botão não redirecionasse para outra página onde estaria o gráfico daquele registro, mas abrisse um modal com o gráfico dele.

Só que eu não sei como fazer pra gerar um gráfico dinâmico dentro de um modal pra cada registro uma vez que esse botão que abre o modal é um botão só que se repete para cada registro.

Procurei em vários lugares e não entendi bem como fazer isso. Alguém sabe como fazer ou uma fonte legal pra aprender?

Uso bootstrap para o front e highcharts para o gráfico.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui vai o código da tabela pra caso alguém se interesse:

### Resultados

```
                        //Pegando os nomes dos campos
                        $num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($qry);//Obtém o número de campos do resultado

                        for($i = 0;$i<$num_fields; $i++){//Pega o nome dos campos
                            $fields[] = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($qry,$i)->name;
                        }

                        //Montando o cabeçalho da tabela
                        $table = '<table class="table table-hover table-inverse"> <tr style="">';

                        for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
                            $table .= '<th>'.$fields[$i].'</th>';
                        }

                        //Montando o corpo da tabela
                        $table .= '<tbody >';
                        while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){
                            $table .= '<tr>';
                            for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
                                $table .= '<td>'.$r[$fields[$i]].'</td>';
                            }

                            // Adicionando botão de edição
                            $table .= '<td><form action="edicao-gptw.php" method="post">'; 
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$r['ID'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JAN PREV" value="'.$r['JAN PREV'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JAN REAL" value="'.$r['JAN REAL'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="FEV PREV" value="'.$r['FEV PREV'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="FEV REAL" value="'.$r['FEV REAL'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAR PREV" value="'.$r['MAR PREV'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAR REAL" value="'.$r['MAR REAL'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ABR PREV" value="'.$r['ABR PREV'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ABR REAL" value="'.$r['ABR REAL'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAI PREV" value="'.$r['MAI PREV'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAI REAL" value="'.$r['MAI REAL'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUN PREV" value="'.$r['JUN PREV'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUN REAL" value="'.$r['JUN REAL'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUL PREV" value="'.$r['JUL PREV'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUL REAL" value="'.$r['JUL REAL'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="AGO PREV" value="'.$r['AGO PREV'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="AGO REAL" value="'.$r['AGO REAL'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="SET PREV" value="'.$r['SET PREV'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="SET REAL" value="'.$r['SET REAL'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="OUT PREV" value="'.$r['OUT PREV'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="OUT REAL" value="'.$r['OUT REAL'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="NOV PREV" value="'.$r['NOV PREV'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="NOV REAL" value="'.$r['NOV REAL'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="DEZ PREV" value="'.$r['DEZ PREV'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="DEZ REAL" value="'.$r['DEZ REAL'].'">';
                            $table .= '<button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></i> Editar </i></button>'; //
                            $table .= '</form></td>';

                            // Adicionando botão de edição
                            $table .= '<td><form action="graf-gptw.php" method="post">'; 
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$r['ID'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JAN PREV" value="'.$r['JAN PREV'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JAN REAL" value="'.$r['JAN REAL'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="FEV PREV" value="'.$r['FEV PREV'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="FEV REAL" value="'.$r['FEV REAL'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAR PREV" value="'.$r['MAR PREV'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAR REAL" value="'.$r['MAR REAL'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ABR PREV" value="'.$r['ABR PREV'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ABR REAL" value="'.$r['ABR REAL'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAI PREV" value="'.$r['MAI PREV'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAI REAL" value="'.$r['MAI REAL'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUN PREV" value="'.$r['JUN PREV'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUN REAL" value="'.$r['JUN REAL'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUL PREV" value="'.$r['JUL PREV'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUL REAL" value="'.$r['JUL REAL'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="AGO PREV" value="'.$r['AGO PREV'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="AGO REAL" value="'.$r['AGO REAL'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="SET PREV" value="'.$r['SET PREV'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="SET REAL" value="'.$r['SET REAL'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="OUT PREV" value="'.$r['OUT PREV'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="OUT REAL" value="'.$r['OUT REAL'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="NOV PREV" value="'.$r['NOV PREV'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="NOV REAL" value="'.$r['NOV REAL'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="DEZ PREV" value="'.$r['DEZ PREV'].'">';
                            $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="DEZ REAL" value="'.$r['DEZ REAL'].'">';
                            $table .= '<!-- Button -->
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                                          Gráfico
                                        </button>

                                        <!-- Modal -->
                                        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                              <div class="modal-header">
                                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Gráfico</h5>
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                </button>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="modal-body">
                                                Aqui entra o gráfico
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                              </div>
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>'; //
                            $table .= '</form></td>';

                        }

                        //Finalizando a tabela
                        $table .= '</tbody></table>';

                        //Imprimindo a tabela
                        echo '<div class="table-table" style="overflow-x:auto;">';
                        echo $table;
                ?>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
                <!--<img class="img-responsive" src="img/640x380/01.jpg" alt="Our Office">-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Quando você clicar no botão **Editar** ou **Gráfico**, ele deveria abrir a modal exibindo a nova página é isso?

Comment: A página editar redireciona pra outra página, mas isso já funciona. O gráfico é diferente, ele deveria abrir um modal com o gráfico dentro. Vou colocar outra imagem.

Comment: Vc pode usar o `include` do php para chamar uma página dentro de outra. Veja aqui mais detalhes https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/265898/abrir-pagina-html-no-modal/265913#265913

Comment: Aaaah, verdade, mas eu posso abrir essa página dentro do modal usando o include? Eu tentei colocar um include ali dentro do modal mas não deu certo.

Comment: @MarianaFerreira certamente! Olhe nesse link da resposta, lá tem um Snipper com dois BTNs chamando modais diferentes cada um com um include dentro. Mas pra vc testar tem que ser em um server local tipo Xamp ou Wamp, pois tem que rodar o PHP.

Comment: Então, isso é legal mas o problema é que fazendo isso, todo botão de gráfico que eu clicar vai abrir o mesmo gráfico e eu preciso que pra cada registro, abra o gráfico correspondente. Eu só não consigo pensar em como eu vou fazer isso.

Comment: Mariana, você viu que no exemplo do @hugoscl, ele faz dois modais diferentes? Bem detalhado.

Comment: @WellingtonTellesCunha exato! Lá eu fiz exatamente isso, 2 btns onde cada um abre seu retrospectivo modal com seu respectivo include dentro. Não estou falando que essa é a melhor maneira do mundo, provavelmente pra sistemas grandes não deve ser, mas dependendo do caso ajuda... Valeu a força!

Comment: Sim, eu vi e achei legal, mas no caso esse é um botão só que vai sendo colocado do lado do registro a cada vez vez que reinicia o while então eu tenho que conseguir fazer um gráfico dinâmico baseado no Id do registro.

Comment: Infelizmente algumas coisas dinâmicas eu tive que ir para o Javascript mesmo não gostando da ideia....ai tem que usar ajax e por ai vai...

Comment: Humm...E pra saber fazer isso mesmo usando ajax eu deveria fazer uma nova pergunta ou só editar essa mesmo?

Comment: Creio que se editar e estiver aberta para Javascript... adicione na informação e inclua na procura, que há mais programadores de java e javascript que nós

Comment: É possível, lógico. O modal nada mais é do que uma HTML escondida no rodapé ou no cabeçalho da sua página, que é mostrado através de um evento de mostrar / esconder através de javascript ou CSS. Isso não impede de alguém colocar dados dinâmicos dentro do corpo.

Comment: - ou mesmo através de iframe... há várias maneiras de fazer.

Comment: Vou deixar essa pergunta pra falar sobre o modal e vou abrir uma nova pra falar sobre o gráfico.